# LibGDX: Move camera with Touch

Tags: android, libgdx, touch, 2d, drag

I create a2D android game with `LibGDX` and I use an orthographic camera to move around the world.

In order to move the camera, the player should touch and drag the screen. So if you touch the screen and drag rightwards, the camera should move left. So it should be just like moving the section of a zoomed picture in the gallery. I hope you are following me.

This is the code:

```
public class CameraTestMain extends ApplicationAdapter {

    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;
    OrthographicCamera camera;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(1280, 720);
        camera.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        handleInput();
        camera.update();

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
        batch.end();
    }

    public void handleInput() {

        // That is my problem

    }

}
```

I don't know what to write in the `handleInput()` method. I know that there is an interface called `InputProcessor` with the method `touchDragged(int x, int y, int pointer)` where you can handle Touch Drag but I have no idea how to use it.

Thanks for your ideas and your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [InputProcessor](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html) is the interface that allows you to define what to do when some action (like for example touching screen) is being performed.

So the first thing is to implement the interface in your class:

```
    public class CameraTestMain extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor
```

then in **create()** method set the class as InputProcessor by calling:

```
    //create() method
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
```

The second one is to implement **touchDragged** method. Notice that it's **x** and **y** parameters are just **relative to last pointer position** so to get actual position of pointer you should save it in some global variable in **touchDown** method. Of course you do not need here the absolute pointer position since you can just **modify** camera position instead of setting this.

```
    //touchDragged method
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        camera.position.set(camera.position.x + screenX, camera.position.y + screenY);
```

Remember to call `camera.update()` at the beginning of **render()** method!

To get more information take a look [at this tutorial](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/10/24/LibGDX-Tutorial-5-Handling-Input-Touch-and-gestures.aspx)

Comment: @erik4thewinners Accept this answer if it helped you out and consider upvoting it since I think it's a good answer.

Comment: screenX and screenY parameters are absolute values.

Comment: This answer is wrong due to the fact that `camera.position.set(camera.position.x + screenX, camera.position.y + screenY);` sends the camera flying away since screenX and screenY return where the mouse is on the screen... Instead of screenX, some sort of "change in X" should be put in, and same for the Y...

Answer (score 18):

This question is old but, as Sierox said, the accepted answer will send the camera flying away, so here's another solution

`Gdx.input.getDeltaX()` will return the difference between the current pointer location and the last pointer location on X axis.

`Gdx.input.getDeltaY()` will return the difference between the current pointer location and the last pointer location on Y axis.

```
@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    float x = Gdx.input.getDeltaX();
    float y = Gdx.input.getDeltaY();

    camera.translate(-x,y);
    return true;
}
```